# XML populates DataTable incorrectly

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, datagridview, odata

I'm using this code to pull xml call from this odata uri. The code pulls the xml and popualtes it into a dataset. I tried populating a datatable with all the tables in the dataset like this:

```
public void CreateObject()
    {
        const string ServerURl = "http://services.odata.org/northwind/northwind.svc/Customers";

         int i =0;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable sourcetable = new DataTable();


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerURl);

        request.ContentType = "application/xml";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        richTextBox1.AppendText(response.StatusDescription);
        var datastream = response.GetResponseStream();          
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(datastream);
        ds.ReadXml(reader);
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];



        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {

           foreach (DataColumn dc in table.Columns)
           {


               if (sourcetable.Columns.Contains(dc.ToString().Trim()) == false)

                 //  MessageBox.Show(dc.ToString());
               {
               sourcetable.Columns.Add(dc.ToString().Trim(),typeof(string));
               }

           }
        }

        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {               

            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {

                sourcetable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
            }
        }

       dataGridView1.DataSource = sourcetable;    

    }
```

The problem is the datagridview gets populated all sorts of messed up. The column names aren't matching the XML structure. It looks like this:

```
+---+---+----------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|   | ID|     Feedid           |                  updated                |               type             |
+---+---+----------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 1 |   |                      |                                         |                                |
| 2 | 1 | 0                    | 2016-02-15T19:04:01Z                    |                                |
| 3 | 2 | Customers            | 0                                       |                                |
| 4 | 3 | Customers            | Customers                               |                                |
| 5 | 4 | Customer             | Customers('ALFKI')                      |                                |
| 6 | 5 | Orders               | Customers('ALFKI')/Orders               | application/atom+xml;type=feed |
| 7 | 6 | CustomerDemographics | Customers('ALFKI')/CustomerDemographics | application/atom+xml;type=feed |
+---+---+----------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Here's a snippet of the XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <feed xml:base="http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <id>http://services.odata.org/northwind/northwind.svc/Customers</id> 
  <title type="text">Customers</title> 
  <updated>2016-02-15T20:31:10Z</updated> 
  <link  rel="self" title="Customers" href="Customers" /> 
- <entry>
  <id>http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ALFKI')</id> 
  <category  term="NorthwindModel.Customer" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
  <link  rel="edit" title="Customer" href="Customers('ALFKI')" /> 
  <link  rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Orders" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Orders" href="Customers('ALFKI')/Orders" /> 

  <link  rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CustomerDemographics" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="CustomerDemographics" href="Customers('ALFKI')/CustomerDemographics" /> 

  <title  /> 
  <updated>2016-02-15T20:31:10Z</updated>  
- <author>
  <name  /> 
  </author>
- <content type="application/xml">
- <m:properties>
  <d:CustomerID>ALFKI</d:CustomerID> 
  <d:CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</d:CompanyName> 
  <d:ContactName>Maria Anders</d:ContactName> 
  <d:ContactTitle>Sales Representative</d:ContactTitle> 
  <d:Address>Obere Str. 57</d:Address>      
  <d:City>Berlin</d:City>    
  <d:Region  m:null="true" />        
  <d:PostalCode>12209</d:PostalCode>         
  <d:Country>Germany</d:Country>         
  <d:Phone>030-0074321</d:Phone>         
  <d:Fax>030-0076545</d:Fax>     
  </m:properties>

  </content>
```

Comment: Have you tried loading a dataset from the XML instead of building tables manually?

Comment: What's the expected output for the datagridview?

Comment: @Justin yes I did but it was returning only one row, the only way i've gotten it to show the complete data is by looping through the dataset, not sure why.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck well feedid, wouldn't be called feed id and the column itself would only have string data. Same thing with the updated column, it's only suppose to have string data. I got the column names from looping through the dataset colums and adding them to the data table so that could be my problem? Maybe I just need to add the columns from the dataset that I know for sure should be grouped together?

Comment: @Sewder Can you post the XML?

Comment: You can just go here http://services.odata.org/northwind/northwind.svc/Customers

And I added a snippet to the question.

Comment: DataTables doesn't work well with very deep xml levels.  The Root tag becomes the DataSet Names.  The next level(s) become the DataTable Names.   Finally the 3rd level is the Data Column names.  Getting any deeper the data gets broken up into more DataTables that make it difficult to associate the data into a flat format that a DataGridView   uses.  The best thing to do in this case is to write your own code to parse the XML into a flat format.

Comment: @jdweng thank you jdweng, do you have documentation on this?

Comment: No, just from a lot of experience.  I usually use either XML Linq (XDocument) or XML Serialize/Deserialize to parse an XML file.